# In which location are the files saved after uploading in Liferay?

Tags: upload, liferay, portlet

I have made a portlet that uploads a document from a form.

I have tried by making a simple dynamic java project and made a `form` to upload the document, that document is saved in `LiferayWorkspace/.metadata/plugins/.../project/document.docx`.

Now I have used this `form` in the portlet and it saves the document, which works fine, but I was wondering where did it save my uploaded document?

I have searched the tomcat directory and possible areas already.

Also if anyone could tell me where does in liferay 6.1 using "Dynamic Data List" portlet, documents are placed after uploading.

Comment: This question is still technically closed as a duplicate of a deleted question, even though the notice banner has been edited out. If it's still relevant, it should be reopened; if it's hopelessly outdated and useless, it should be deleted. Knowing nothing about liferay, I can't tell which it is.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen technically the question is valid, but on a best practice level, the question asks for an implementation detail that's not really related to programming (at least not the way it's asked here) and it's borderline off-topic as not programming related or too broad, although coming from a programmer's background. I see it misleading people with a similar problem rather than providing a path that should be followed. As it's a rare question, in the end: I don't care if it stays closed, is reopened or what else. Not sure if that helps, I'd just leave it as is, given its age.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Liferay has its configuration settings stored in portal-ext.properties which is placed in liferay-portal-tomcat-6.1/liferay-portal-6.1/ directory.

you can change from there as well

```
#
# FileStore
#
dl.store.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/document_library
```

Comment: Just a little clarification: Liferay does not have its configuration settings stored in `portal-ext.properties`, it is stored in `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar/portal.properties` and to override this configuration we `create` a `portal-ext.properties` and use that same property in our `portal-ext.properties`. You don't get a `portal-ext.properties` by default as you have mentioned in your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The default store folder is `portal-folder/data/document_library` but you can change it by liferay configuration.

Answer (score 1):

These are the properties in `ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar/portal.properties` which define where liferay stores the documents, you can override these properties by creating a `portal-ext.properties` and including your custom value:

```
#
# FileSystemStore
#
dl.store.file.system.root.dir=${liferay.home}/data/document_library
```

Additionally,
You can also set the `temp` (temporary) directory for the files uploaded, i.e. when you use `UploadRequest` to the get the file from request liferay stores them temporarily on the server:

```
#
# Set the temp directory for uploaded files.
#
#com.liferay.portal.upload.UploadServletRequestImpl.temp.dir=C:/Temp
```